# Custom tokenizer for apache lucene 4

Tags: java, apache, lucene, tokenize

I have a tokenized text(splitted sentences and splitted words). And going to create Apache Lucene index, based on this structure. What is the easiest way to extend or replace a standart tokenizer to use custom tokens. I was looking at StandardTokenizerImpl, but seems very complex. May be there are any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

StandardTokenizerImpl is complex because it has been generated from a JFlex grammar.

If you want to implement your own tokenizer, all you need to do is to extend the [Tokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Tokenizer.html?is-external=true) class.

For example, [WhitespaceTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceTokenizer.html) is a simple tokenizer that splits tokens at whitespaces.

Comment: It doesn't fulfil requirement to index Sentences.